# How to save a shortcode foreach custom post type you create in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, shortcode

well basically what i'm trying to do is create a Shortcode foreach cpt(custom post type) i create in my wordpress plugin but i can't find out why when i use the shortcode it returns the code itself like when i use [my_shortcode_324] it returns the same thing

```
if ( ! class_exists('My_Plugin_Shortcode') ){

    class My_Plugin_Shortcode{
        public $cptID;
        public function __construct($cptID){
            $this->cptID = $cptID;
            add_shortcode('my_plugin_'.$this->cptID, array($this, 'add_special_shortcode'));
        }

        public function add_special_shortcode($atts = array(), $content = null, $tag = ''){
            $atts = array_change_key_case( (array) $atts, CASE_LOWER);
            $cptID = $this->cptID;
            extract( shortcode_atts(
                array(
                    'id' => $cptID,
                    'orderby' => 'date'
                ),
                $atts,
                $tag
            ));
            ob_start();
            require( MY_PLUGIN_PATH . 'views/my-plugin_shortcode.php');
            return ob_get_clean();
        }
    }
}
```

And on the custom post class on the save method :

```
public function save_post( $post_id ){
            if ( isset( $_POST['my_plugin_nonce'] )){
                if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['my_plugin_nonce'], 'my_plugin_nonce' )){
                    return;
                }
            }
            if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE){
                return;
            }
             // Instantiate the My_Plugin_Shortcode class when saving the CPT
            $my_plugin_shortcode = new My_Plugin_Shortcode($post_id);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing might be due to the fact that you're creating an instance of the '**My_Plugin_Shortcode**' class within the '**save_post**' method, which might not be the ideal place for shortcode registration. Shortcodes are typically registered during WordPress initialization.

To fix this, you should move the instantiation of the '**My_Plugin_Shortcode**' class to a more appropriate hook like '**init**'.

This way, the shortcode will be registered properly and should work as expected when you use it within your content.

Comment: Thank you that was indeed the problem, i just moved the instantiation to the construction where the 'init' hook is located and it fixed the problem. Thank you again